# How to reduce factorization into Independent Set Problem?

Tags: rsa

Is it possible to reduce RSA (basically factorization) into a NP-Complete problem, concretely the ISP (Independent Set Problem)?

If so, which as far as I know is possible, how is it done?

I can't imagine how a problem like factorization could be interpreted as a binary symmetric matrix.

Comment: May I ask how do you know it? The decision version of IF is known to be in $NP\cap co-NP$ so I really doubt whether it is NP complete.

Comment: Isn't every NP reducible to an NP-Complete?

 - From wikipedia:
"the definition of an NP-complete problem states that every problem in NP must be quickly reducible to every NP-complete problem (that is, it can be reduced in polynomial time)"

Comment: I am not saying factorization is in NP-Complete. I am saying that as being in NP, it should be reducible to an NP-Complete.

Comment: So basically you are asking how we could use an efficient solution to ISP to factor large numbers, correct?

Comment: My guess is that the easiest way to do this is use the fact that all NP-complete problems reduce to each other, then show how some other NP-Complete problem (e.g., boolean satisfiability) could be used to solve IF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF can be reduced to 3SAT. This was already addressed here before - https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11718/generating-3sat-circuit-for-integer-factorization-example

It should easy to convert that 3SAT to ISP - http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/wiki/pub/ABI/ComputabilityComplexityWS11/Complexity2.pdf